If i quit emulation station, can i go back? Because i want to go to my regular raspberry pi desktop, but do not want to loose ES progress
I would like to know if I can go back to Emulation Station after quitting. I am running a Pi 4 and wondering if I can go back afterward and keep my ES progress on my games.

Help would be apprieciated!

what have you tried?

why do you believe that your question is about the Raspberry Pi?

I haven't tried anything because I hope I won't loose any progress on emulation station. I am hoping I can get back to it before I quit. I want to get back to the regular Raspberry Pi Desktop

you are using a linux computer that is capable of doing multiple things at the same time ... you should be able to switch to the desktop without quiting your program

Ok, I am using a Pi4, I don't know if that us a Linux or not

Is that what "splash screens" does. Sorry I misread the first time
